# Verificar se o item existe em uma List<>

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, lista

Tenho uma lista tipada em C# e preciso procurar nela um item através de vários filtros. Demostrando em códigos:

```
List<LoteRecla> listLoteRecla = new List<LoteRecla>();
```

Tentei utilizar o método .Exists() filtrando por apenas um campo dessa lista, conforme abaixo e funcionou normalmente.

```
    if (!listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.est_lote.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["est_lote"].ToString())))
```

Porém me solicitaram para utilizar mais filtros, tentei fazer da forma abaixo:

```
if (!listLoteRecla.Exists(
                                x => x.est_lote.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["est_lote"].ToString()) &&
                                x.id_log_unidade.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unidade"]) &&
                                x.id_log_unid_local.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unid_local"]) &&
                                x.loc_rua.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_rua"]) &&
                                x.loc_num.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_num"].ToString()) &&
                                x.loc_altura.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_altura"].ToString()) &&
                                x.id_log_produto.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto"]) &&
                                x.id_log_produto_emb.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto_emb"])))
                            {
```

Porém desse forma não está funcionando, eu passo por dados iguais e não deveria entrar no IF, mas está entrando.

Estou fazendo algo errado?
Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso que preciso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Vai colocando um por um e veja qual causa uma mudança. Talvez você está encontrando um valor inesperado. Talvez esteja usando uma condição errada. Não dá para saber sem ter acesso aos seus dados. Ou seja, você tem que depurar o código para descobri o que está acontecendo. Avalie as expressões no *debugger* quando chegar neste ponto, veja se está tudo de acordo com o que você espera. Pode até ser que o código tenha algo errado mas não temos como saber.

Comment: ok, vou ir adicionando um por um para testar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma correta é usando [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc679431(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
if (!listLoteRecla.Any(
                            x => x.est_lote.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["est_lote"].ToString()) &&
                            x.id_log_unidade.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unidade"]) &&
                            x.id_log_unid_local.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unid_local"]) &&
                            x.loc_rua.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_rua"]) &&
                            x.loc_num.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_num"].ToString()) &&
                            x.loc_altura.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_altura"].ToString()) &&
                            x.id_log_produto.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto"]) &&
                            x.id_log_produto_emb.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto_emb"])))
                        {
```

Comment: Não vejo por que funcionaria como Any e não com Exists, afinal o comportamento de ambos algoritimos é semelhante.
Mas isto não muito o fato do Any ser preferivel.

Comment: @TobyMosque [Porque `Exists` não está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352821(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Any é um método extensivo, ele funciona para qual quer IEnumerable, equanto que Exists é um método do objeto List<> que existe desde o .NET 2.0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @TobyMosque Então você prefere usar um método mais antigo do que um método dedicado, que trabalha com maior sinergia com o provedor de dados?

Comment: Eu mesmo disse que o Any é preferivel e dei um up vote na sua resposta, apenas disse que o retorno dos dois deveria ser o mesmo, apesar do Any apresentar uma perfomance superior.

Comment: @TobyMosque Exatamente, e agradeço. `Exists` neste caso deve ser desencorajado.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz dessa forma e funcionou.

```
if (!listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.est_lote.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["est_lote"].ToString())) && 
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.id_log_unidade.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unidade"])) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.id_log_unid_local.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_unid_local"])) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.loc_rua.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_rua"])) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.loc_num.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_num"].ToString())) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.loc_altura.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["loc_altura"].ToString())) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.id_log_produto.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto"])) &&
    !listLoteRecla.Exists(x => x.id_log_produto_emb.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["id_log_produto_emb"]))){
```

Porém agora estou em outra situação que vou precisar de uma ajuda também.

Quero recuperar o index da linha da lista filtrando pelos mesmo campos acima, tentei com o método .FindIndex() e ele só da certo com um parâmetro, conforme abaixo.

```
int index = listLoteRecla.FindIndex(x => x.est_lote.Equals(dtDados.Rows[i]["est_lote"].ToString()));
```

Se eu tentar adicionar mais parâmetros nele não dá certo.

Tem algum outro método que faça algo assim? Ou algum exemplo que eu possa utilizar o .FindIndex() mesmo?

Comment: Se você encontrou outro problema, edite a sua pergunta com o novo problema, não responda a sua pergunta com outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

fiz utilizando a ideia de Predicate<> e deu certo e até no Code Metrics o método ficou mais limpo. Ficou assim:

Chamada:

```
int index = listLoteRecla.FindIndex(LogicaDeBuscaEditar);
```

Método:

```
private static bool LogicaDeBuscaEditar(LoteRecla obj)
        {
            if(obj.est_lote.Equals(dtRowGlobal["est_lote"].ToString()) &&
                obj.id_log_produto.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(dtRowGlobal["id_log_produto"])) &&
                obj.id_log_produto_emb.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(dtRowGlobal["id_log_produto_emb"])) &&
                obj.id_log_unid_local.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(dtRowGlobal["id_log_unid_local"])) &&
                obj.id_log_unidade.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(dtRowGlobal["id_log_unidade"])) &&
                obj.loc_altura.Equals(dtRowGlobal["loc_altura"].ToString()) &&
                obj.loc_num.Equals(dtRowGlobal["loc_num"].ToString()) &&
                obj.loc_rua.Equals(dtRowGlobal["loc_rua"].ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Achei que ficou organizado assim pois toda a regra de validação ficou em outro método.

Obrigado.